# Max Count from Framed SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the query below that is selected data in a 'framed' manner. There is a lot of data and I only want to get one 'page' at a time.

```
SELECT
    entryDateTime,
    value
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY entryDateTime DESC) AS rowNum,
        entryDateTime,
        value
    FROM
        table
    WHERE
        entryDateTime BETWEEN @start AND @end
) AS TempTbl
WHERE
    rowNum BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow;
```

I want to know if it's possible to get the maximum `rowNum` value from this. Basically, I am looking to get a count of all possible rows so I know how many pages of data exist for the given time span (I expect the maximum `rowNum` to be bigger than `@endRow`). Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would execute 2 separate queries, one that just does a COUNT(*), and then a separate one that gets the current page of data.

Comment: That is what I am doing now, it's just that my count query takes a long time. I have 150 row pages and 4,000+ pages. I was just hoping I could extract that total value from my subquery somehow.

Comment: If a count(*) query takes a long time it probably means you need to revise the query, or introduce some indexes to your database.  Looking at your query I would put a clustered index on entryDateTime.

Comment: The table is well indexed. The problem is that I am looking at about 600,000 rows in a table with nearly 700,000,000.

Comment: Did you try a clustered index on entryDateTime.  Having it clustered vs non-clustered is important in this case.